# How to add multiple values of numpy array to a plot legend?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, knn

For my experiment, I am using KNN to classify a few datasets (shared [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WX1XRvzjLU2NkUBmzN9sxUW5AhUOFigw) for reproducibility). Hereunder is my source code.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt




types = {
        "Data_G": ["datag_s.csv", "datag_m.csv"], 
        "Data_V": ["datav_s.csv", "datav_m.csv"], 
        "Data_C": ["datac_s.csv", "datac_m.csv"], 
        "Data_R": ["datar_s.csv", "datar_m.csv"]
        }

dataset = None
ground_truth = None

for idx, csv_list in types.items():
    for csv_f in csv_list:

        col_time,col_window = np.loadtxt(csv_f,delimiter=',').T
        trailing_window = col_window[:-1] # "past" values at a given index
        leading_window  = col_window[1:]  # "current values at a given index
        decreasing_inds = np.where(leading_window < trailing_window)[0]
        beta_value = leading_window[decreasing_inds]/trailing_window[decreasing_inds]
        quotient_times = col_time[decreasing_inds]

        my_data = genfromtxt(csv_f, delimiter=',')
        my_data = my_data[:,1]
        my_data = my_data[:int(my_data.shape[0]-my_data.shape[0]%200)].reshape(-1, 200)
        labels = np.full(1, idx)

        if dataset is None:
            dataset = beta_value.reshape(1,-1)[:,:15]
        else:
            dataset = np.concatenate((dataset,beta_value.reshape(1,-1)[:,:15]))

        if ground_truth is None:
            ground_truth = labels
        else:
            ground_truth = np.concatenate((ground_truth,labels))



X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dataset, ground_truth, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

knn_classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3, weights='distance', algorithm='auto', leaf_size=300, p=2, metric='minkowski')
knn_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

When I do the following

```
plot_data=dataset.transpose()
plt.plot(plot_data)
```

It produces the following plot.

[image]

I added the legend to the plot as the following:

```
plt.plot(plot_data, label=idx)
plt.legend()
```

[image]

However, as it is seen, it is replacing all the legends with `Data_R`. What am I doing wrong in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I'll say before answering this question is that I'd always be cautious when looping over dictionaries. Prior to Python 3.6 dictionaries aren't ordered, so if you need to guarantee order in your dictionary you should use an `OrderedDict`. If you're running Python3.6+ then this is something you don't need to worry about. Anyway...

After the for loop `for idx, csv_list in types.items():` we will always have that `idx = "Data_R"` (given that your dictionary is ordered).

So, when you're plotting with `plt.plot(plot_data, label=idx)` the labels of all the lines will be set as `"Data_R"`.

Instead, you should loop over the lines and add the labels to them one at a time.

```
for i, key in enumerate(types.keys()):
    plt.plot(plot_data[:, 2*i], label=key)
    plt.plot(plot_data[:, 2*i+1], label=key)

plt.legend()
```

Comment: Thank you but why `2*i` and why are do we have two `plt.plot`?

Comment: Because ```data_plot``` has shape ```(15, 8)```. That is, we have two lines for each dataset, hence two calls to ```plt.plot``` for each key.

Comment: The for loop is, of course, optional. If you'd rather you could just add the lines one at a time: ```plt.plot(plot_data[:, 0], label="Data_?"```, ```plt.plot(plot_data[:, 1, label="Data_?```, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I have accepted your answer! But to be honest, I don't know why I am getting two lines for each dataset. Does KNN treat one line for ground truth and one line for testing?

Comment: Thank you. I've not used KNN before so I'm not sure (this could be a good follow up question). However, as an outsider, I can see that you have two csv's for each key? Also, as I understand, in this kind of thing isn't it common to have a training dataset and a testing dataset?

Comment: Right but I am haveing training and testing `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dataset, ground_truth, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
`. So probably, I have to merge the CSV files instead?

Comment: I see. Merging the CSV files does seem sensible to me. But I guess an obvious question is why were the csv's separate in the first place? There must have been a reason, no? **Regardless of this, this is all conjecture and I don't actually know what I'm talking about**. I'd consider posting a follow-up question.

Comment: It's OK but the reason why I have two CSV files is because they are captured separately.

Comment: The second line is not needed and can be replaced with `plt.plot(plot_data[:, [i, i +1]], label = key)` as they don't seem to refer to different datasets... Edit: as I  general note I would advice against using `plt.plot` as it refers to the last opened figure/axes, it's more 'pythonic' to use the OOB approach recommended by matplotlib.

Comment: Good spot that we can remove the second call to ```plt.plot()```. However it would need to be ```plt.plot(plot_data[:, [2*i, 2*i+1]], label=key)``` not ```plt.plot(plot_data[:, [i, i +1]], label = key)```. I generally work with the OO interface, however the state machine is often sufficient.

Comment: Thank you. Instead of 8 lines in the plot, I want only 4 of them. How can I remove the remaining 4 lines?

Comment: This depends which 4 lines you want to plot. If you don't want to plot both lines for each dataset you can just remove one of the calls to ```plt.plot``` in the for loop in my solution.

Comment: You are awesome and thank you. That solved my problem.

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad I could help you :)